# Как определить степень покрытия кода тестами?

Tags: юнит-тесты

В своей практике неоднократно убеждался, что использовать юнит-тесты при написании кода - важно и полезно, но для меня остаётся не совсем ясным один момент:
К примеру, я хочу создать новую страничку для своего WPF-приложения. Следовательно, я пишу тесты для ViewModel-класса. Согласно принципу Test-First, я должен сначала написать тесты для своего кода, а затем уже добиваться их прохождения через написание кода. Но не совсем понятно, какой объём кода тестов мне нужен. Должен ли я протестировать только выполнение команд? Какие именно блоки нужно тестировать? Есть ли какой-нибудь общий алгоритм? Как оценить степень покрытия кода класса тестами? Может, посоветуете какую-нибудь литературу (желательно с примерами на .NET и VS)

Comment: Visual Studio ж вроде умеет определять степень покрытия, нет?

Comment: Ну здесь вопрос скорее в том, как изначально определить, какие тесты нужно написать, чтобы создать новый класс. Скажем так, необходимый минимум для какого-либо конкретного примера.

Comment: А это вопрос спецификации. Тестировать нужно не на уровне классов, классы — деталь реализации. Тестировать нужно на уровне спецификации. Для каждого требования оттуда — один или несколько тестов, которые это требование **полностью** проверяют. (Ну, насколько возможно.)

Comment: @VladD, это отличный подход (он же тестирование черного ящика), когда мы делаем тесты "для дяди". А вот для себя ... Тут уже объем исчерпывающей спецификации станет большим, чем объем программы (ЯП (особенно если не писать длинные идентификаторы) все же лаконичней ЕЯ). И тут мы понимаем, что тестировать все же надежней белый ящик, т.е. конкретную реализацию. Не знаю, если честно, как тут формализовать, видимо на самом деле тестирование это все же искусство поиска "болевых точек".

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, нужно всё равно, хотя бы для себя, написать **спецификацию** юнита: что мы ожидаем от него (то есть, на это имею право рассчитывать другие модули), и что не должно быть гарантировано, и является деталью реализации (и модули, которые опираются на это, не правы и должны быть исправлены). Имея такую самодельную спецификацию, вполне можно писать к ней юнит-тесты.

Comment: @VladD, это верно. Я же говорю об ее объеме, необходимом для написания тестов охватывающих все граничные случаи (в т.ч. их возможного взаимовлияния). Если подходить формально, то количество тестов может стать очень большим.

Comment: @avp: Ну или мы можем намеренно ограничить функциональность. Например, сказать, что на вход подаются только маленькие числа, и строки не больше килобайта. Но всё равно эти ограничения должны быть проговорены, потому что **юнит болжен быть boack box'ом для его пользователей**. Иначе всем придётся держать в голове все неявные, да ещё и наверняка часто изменяющиеся требования (а требования будут меняться, раз они не специфицированы), и это будет приводить к багам. Подход без спецификации в том или ином виде могут позволить себе лишь маленькие проекты (а для таких тесты не нужны, как мне кажется).

Comment: @avp: Вообще, разделение на модули и формализация требований к модулям нужны только начиная с некоторой сложности проекта. Например, для типичных юниксовских утилит такой единицей является одна, целая утилита. А её спецификация — man. То, что юниксовские утилиты — именно модули, следует из того, что в хорошем скрипте они _комбинируются_.